# Issue with JS function+Advanced custome fields, can't take data form dynamic item

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I combined a jquery slider with the repeater fields.
under the repeater, I have 2 subfields. one called “image_carousel1” and the other “image_carousel_discription”

this slider has a class called “sc-selected” that dynamically appear when an image is selected. (when this class is on an image the image change it’s size).

I’m trying to define that when the class “sc-selected” is on some image and the “data-row” is equal in “image11” and “change_h2″ the “image_carousel_discription” form the same row of the “image_carousel1” will appear,(I defined that in JS func)

this is the code that displays the images and the titles

```
  <?php

 // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  $i = 1;
  if( have_rows(‘carousel_images’) ):
 // loop through the rows use_cases_fields data
 while ( have_rows(‘carousel_images’) ) : the_row();
   $title=get_sub_field(‘image_carousel_discription’);
   $image = get_sub_field(‘image_carousel1’);

     if( !empty($image) ):
 // thumbnail
$thumb = $image;
  ?>

  <li id=”image11″ data-row=”<?php echo $i; ?>” > <a
   href=”#home”>“/>
<h2 id=”change_h2″ data-row=”<?php echo $i; ?>”><?php
    echo $title ?></h2>

   <?php $i++; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
  endwhile;
 endif;
 ?>
```

JS- the “carousel on” adding the class “sc-selected” to image.

```
   carousel.on(‘itemSelected.sc’, function (evt) {

$(“#change_h2”).each(function(index, elem){

 $(“#image11”).each(function(index2, elem2){
  var itemH3 = $(elem).attr(‘data-row’);
    var itemImg = $(elem2).attr(‘data-row’);

   if (itemH3==itemImg){
  var div1 = document.getElementById(“change_h2”);
var align = div1.getAttribute(“data-row”);

  console.log(align);

}
 });
 });

});
```

My problem is with the javascript function, the data row always stays on the first row and in every image that selected it keep showing in console log “1”
(the first data-row)

Comment: You should not have multiple identical ids. ids should be a unique identifier. use classes instead.

Comment: also - since you have identical ids, your div1 will always just get the first one, which will always have the data-row 1 - you need to make sure that the js is only looking in the correct element

Comment: do u have a suggestion how can I make sure that js looking for the correct element?